# How to pass data (few strings) from Activity to Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

What is the best way (most simple) to get some data from Activity to Fragment in Android?

I've got one or more Strings and I need to use (or display) them in Fragment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step #1: Use `findFragmentById()` or `findFragmentByTag()` to find the fragment.

Step #2: Call a method on the fragment.